# C# Windows Application - Setting Tab Control Transfer between input fields

Tags: c#

I developed a windows application. The input screen has two date pickers followed by a set of textbox as input fields.

- After checking on the Dates
- When I click on Tab Control, Cursor is not transferred for next input, it goes to submit button

What settings should i specify to transfer control sequentially across the input text boxes before finally hitting submit button

Thanks in Advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `TabIndex` property of each control.

To help with that, you can click the `Tab Order` button in the WinForms designer toolbar, then click the controls in your desired order to set their TabIndicies.